# ImportError Faker Package Still

Tags: python-3.x, faker

Trying to create dummy data from a dataset.

Looked for hours to see why I'm getting this ImportError. I have Faker 2.0.0 installed.

```
import unicodecsv as csv
from faker import Faker
from collections import defaultdict
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Faker' from 'faker' (unknown
>   location)

Receiving this error message still! I tried using solutions from other forum questions, to avail. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: How have you installed Faker? If using zip file, then you can uninstall it and install using python -m pip install Faker

Comment: I installed Faker using PyPi. What do you mean using the zip file?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. If you are dealing with the same issue look in your Scripts folder within your Python directory. You'll find an application named faker also. Rename it and you'll be good to go.